# get all users from a group in Active Directory using GroupPrincipal

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Im trying to get all users of a particular group in AD but i am getting Exception : "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist."

```
//using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
          using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainName"))
          {
             //using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, windowsGroup.TrimEnd('*')))
             using (var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "groupName"))
             {
                if (groupPrincipal != null)
                {
                   var users = groupPrincipal.GetMembers();
                   foreach (UserPrincipal userPrincipal in users)
                   {
                      //user variable has the details about the user 
                   }
                }
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

use container to specify your root

```
using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "TEST.COM", "DC=TEST,DC=COM"))
                {
                    //using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, windowsGroup.TrimEnd('*')))
                    using (var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "groupName"))
                    {
                        if (groupPrincipal != null)
                        {
                            var users = groupPrincipal.GetMembers();
                            foreach (UserPrincipal userPrincipal in users)
                            {
                                //user variable has the details about the user 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```